# What do I do with this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388358/optimized-sql-server-code-didnt-change-much-but-saved-a-few-minutes). It then came to pass that, basically, there were other issues linked to how we were running the SQL in the first place, and once we updated the stored procedure with the "optimized" code, the performance gain went away.

Should I edit the question, delete, write and accept an answer that details what we found?

Comment: I get 'page not found'.  I don't know if it's due to my 'rep-score' or if it has been deleted.  In either case, this is really irritating!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a close reason under offtopic that states:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

If the fix was unrelated to the information posted in the question, then that would quite plausibly fit your situation.  Just explain the situation briefly in comments and flag the question for closure for that reason.

On the other hand, if your fix was something that someone else could have arrived at, and that others with the same problems described in your question would benefit from getting the same solution, then write up what you did in an answer.

Answer (score 10):

There's no "right answer" here - if you think that you can write an answer that will be useful to future readers, then go ahead and do so. If you think that the question isn't worth salvaging, delete it. Only you know the details of what you've discovered so you're going to have to use your judgement.